# How to get all of the content from my Wordpress blog behind Azure's Application Gateway to direct to the proper service?

Tags: .net, wordpress, azure, azure-application-gateway

I have a .NET website and Wordpress blog (I'm using a theme) hosted in Azure.  Both are behind an Application Gateway.  I have a path based route for the blog pointing at /StayorVaycay/Blog, and for the most part, that works.  The website is up and the blog page opens.  However, the page looks weird because not all of the files that need to load are pointing to the proper service.  Some, again not all, of the needed blog files are pointing to the blog service and are loading, but the others are pointing to the website service where the files do not exist.  The blog site is at StayorVaycay.com/StayorVaycay/Blog.  Feel free to look to see what I am referring to.  Just an FYI, the blog is not linked in the website because it is clearly not ready so only if you know how to get to it, can you access it.

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the configuration for App Gateway.

Comment: @BhargaviAnnadevara-MSFT, any particular part of the configuration?  Backend pools, HTTP settings, Frontend IP configurations, etc.?